# Infinite-loop question: Is it possible to make a "Copy this code to share", with a "copy this code to share" inside of it?

Tags: html, infinite-loop

I want to make a blog that everyone can copy the HTML of the blog (which contains links, pics, and text) to share on their own blog. I want the blog that they share to also have this "copy and share" feature and when people copy from their blog, the "copy and share" stays with the blog. Make sense?

The problem I see is that I would have to create an infinity long script of "share this" inside the shared content. Not possible.

I could possibly do this with an iframe, but I don't think blogs usually allow iframes, do they?

For example:

> "Please share this stack
>   overflow question! Copy this html and
>   repost anywhere:"
>
> ```
> <iframe src="stackoverflow.com/my_question"></iframe>
> ```

... and obviously, my question would then have a link to repost it.

Bla! My mind is going to explode! I can't explain this anymore!

Someone please help me understand what I want to do, or tell me it's impossible. Thanks!

Comment: My blog software allows iframes...

Comment: What about pointing them to File -> Save As -> Webpage, Complete?

Comment: I don't think he wants to make it easy to copy *all* the HTML, just the blogposts themselves.. :-) Right?

Comment: "[C]opy the HTML of the blog (which contains links, pics, and text)" -- that sounds like everything to me. :)

Comment: No, it sounds like the blog post (which has links pics and text).

Answer (score 0):

You make the "Share this" a button, that with javascript shows a box (made with a DIV) with the HTML to copy/paste.

The box should then include everything you need to share. That then includes the button and Javascript for sharing. That way when they copy and paste the code to share, they also include the "Share this button"

No infinite recursion needed.

Comment: Sure, here is one: http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/

Comment: I don't see how this helps my cause. I want it infinitely copy and paste-able with a "Share This button", on my blog, a blog that copies it, and the blog that copies the copier, and so on. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, I understood you the first time. I've updated my answer to hopefully be clearer.