# Is it possible to copy javascript with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to copy javascript with javascript? For example:

```
<div class="copyThis">
    <script language="javascript">
        $(function()
        {
            $("#click").click(function(e){
                $('.copyThis').clone().appendTo('#copyArea');
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
     CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 50px; background-color: gray;">
        <a id="click" href="">click here to copy</a>
    </div>
    <div id="copyArea">
         Put here:
    </div>
</div>
```

But this doesn't copy the  tag and its content. At least, not that I know of.

**NOTE:**
I came upon this question in relationship to a different question I had posted here: [Infinite-loop question: Is it possible to make a "Copy this code to share", with a "copy this code to share" inside of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4453593/infinite-loop-question-is-it-possible-to-make-a-copy-this-code-to-share-with)
I hope it's ok to post this question separately as it's sort of a curiosity thing.

Comment: you should add a jquery tag here since this isn't plain javascript

Comment: you should use a class, not an ID. ID's are supposed to be unique. If you're trying to continue to use an event, maybe you should use some event delegation.

Comment: Why do you want the script tags to be cloned?

Comment: what are you trying to do. I feel like there's a much better way of doing what you're doing if you would just explain your overall plan.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I think this is what you want.  This ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a47tz/2/)) will fill a textarea for easy copying:

```
<div id="copyThis">
    <script language="javascript">
                $(function()
                {
                    $("#click").click(function(e){
                        $('#copyArea').val($('#copyThis').html());
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });
                });
            </script>
     CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT CONTENT
    <div style="width: 200px; height: 50px; background-color: gray;">
        <a id="click" href="">click here to copy</a>
    </div>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="40" id="copyArea"></textarea>
</div>
```

---

You were doing DOM manipulation before [`ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).  Use:

```
        <script language="javascript">
            $(function()
            {
                $("#click").click(function(e){
                    $('#copyThis').clone().appendTo('#copyArea');
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
            });
        </script>
```

See [the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a47tz/1/).

Comment: didn't work. It copies everything, just not the <script> tags.

Comment: Should not be a problem in this case, as the code *follows* the element.

Comment: It copies everything accept the <script>. Am I wrong? I'm trying to make a "copy this" button that will include a "copy this" button when posted elsewhere from copying. Make sense?

Comment: @Pointy, you're wrong.  Jacob and I are correct, and I hope he undeletes his answer.  The node set is created when the selector is called.  That is before `ready`, so the set is empty.  It stays empty.  It would be different if `live` or `delegate` were used.

Comment: @Dave, are you trying to copy it into a textarea or something?

Comment: Ah OK @Matthew, I'm sorry -- I thought that the clicking was happening on the cloned `<div>` itself, and not on that separate element. I'll revise my answer.

Comment: @matthew Yes, I'm trying to copy into a textarea for a "share this" sort of thing.

Comment: @Dave, so you want a [quine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_%28computing%29). ;)  Look at innerHTML.

Comment: @matthew A quine! That's what you call it! Thank you! I feel like no one understands me because they don't realize it's a "quine". Maybe you can help me over on my other post! (link in question)

Comment: Yes, there are multiple ways to do quines, but with the JavaScript DOM, one of the easiest approaches is what I added to my answer.  Of course, quine purists would regard that as cheating. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** this answer is to a question different from the one actually asked :-)  I'll leave it here as a historical curiosity however.

---

The problem is very likely to be that your `<script>` tags are just not being executed. If what you want to happen is that your cloned `<div>` have the same "click" handler, however, you should really go about it in a totally different way:

1. Use a "class" instead of an "id" to mark the `<div>` elements that should be affected; say, "cloneMe"
2. Use the jQuery `.live()` or (better) `.delegate()` facilities to set up the handler so that it operates off of bubbled events, and can therefore handle clicks on cloned `<div>` blocks.

(then in your Javascript somewhere: )

```
$(function() {
  $('body').delegate("div.cloneMe", "click", function(ev) {
    $(this).clone().appendTo('#copyArea');
    ev.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Now you should be able to clone to your heart's content, and you don't have to worry about that bad old Javascript jammed so obtrusively into your code.

*edit* — ah - I now see that I was completely confused about what it was that was getting clicked. If the clicking is happening on a separate button (or `<a>` or whatever), then there's really no need to have the script stuck in the middle of the page at all; the whole thing should just be a simple event handler setup.

Comment: The script tag was always being executed.  It's just that (before he added my `ready` fix) the DOM wasn't loaded yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think in a round about way what your trying to do is covered by jquery's live methods.

```
<div class="copy">
  <a class="click-me">click me</click>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.click-me').live('click',function(e){
$(e).parent().clone().appendTo('#copyArea');
})
</script>
```

Using Live will re-bind the new element to the click handler without having to copy a javascript block

Answer (score 0):

If you want the click event to be cloned also, you need to set the [withDataAndEvents](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) argument to true in clone

$('.copyThis').clone(true).appendTo('#copyArea');